Does Krittivasa ramayana say Bhagiratha was born to two women?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qs36z8jocFg
This video says the king passed away before the boon for a child could be fulfilled in the normal way and Siva and the Devas allowed the two wives to conceive Bhagiratha.
There is also a folk etymology that his name means "born of women".

This does happen in Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa, but it's not the case in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. Kṛttivāsa Rāmāyaṇa is not a prāmāṇya grantha, instead it's a lokasāhitya grantha, which is based on Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, etc.
